# How to pass the previous data using spinner and image?

Tags: java, android

I have problem with my android coding. I want to make an update process. But first of all, I'm trying to collect all the data from edit text, spinner and image. But I have problem with spinner and image, could not get the previous data. How to get the previous data using spinner and image? Ex.. Image1

[image: Image1]

shows the complete retrieve process when user click on Submit Button, then it will go to this View Activity interface. While in Image2

[image: Image2]

shows the Edit Activity interface where the user can update all the data from there when the user click on Edit Button. The issue now is, I can not collect the previous data using spinner and image for editing/updating purposes as shown in the Image 2. Really hope someone can help me.. Thanks in advance...

Coding as follows:

**1) Coding from View Activity:-**

```
    EditAdsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent editAds = new Intent(ViewAdsActivity.this, EditAdsActivity.class);
            startActivity(editAds);

            String tn = ViewTuitionName.getText().toString();
            String pn = ViewProviderName.getText().toString();
            String pg = getIntent().getStringExtra("PG");

            Intent i = new Intent(ViewAdsActivity.this, EditAdsActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("TN", "" +tn);   // Collected from EditText or any other source
            i.putExtra("PN", "" +pn);
            i.putExtra("PG", "" +pg);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

**2) Coding from Edit Activity (onCreate method):-**

```
    Intent i = getIntent();
    String tn = i.getStringExtra("TN");
    String pn = i.getStringExtra("PN");
    String pg = getIntent().getStringExtra("PG");

    EditTuitionName.setText(tn);
    EditProviderName.setText(pn);
    EditProviderGender.setSelection(pg);
```

Comment: So you want to pass the selected item in spinner and uploaded image to EditActivity?

Comment: Please show the full code of your ViewActivity

Comment: Yes, I want like that @SonTruong. I cannot paste all the code here, its long :'(

Comment: Ok just show me the code where you init your spinner and render an image into your image view.

Comment: EditTuitionImage = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.edit_tuition_image);

Comment: EditProviderGender = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.edit_tuition_provider_gender);

Comment: Sir, can I email you the coding so its much easier you can see all my coding and which part did I miss...

Comment: done email you sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution:

**Constant.java**

```
public class Constant {
    public static final String[] GENDER = {"Male", "Female", "Other"};
}
```

**ViewAdsActivity.java**

```
public class ViewAdsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CircleImageView avatar;
    private EditText name;
    private Spinner gender;
    private Button next;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_ads);

        avatar = findViewById(R.id.avatar);
        name = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_name);
        gender = findViewById(R.id.spinner_gender);
        next = findViewById(R.id.button_next);


        // Render avatar
        String imageUrl = "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/spiritedaway/images/6/69/Chihiro.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20170308090934";
        avatar.setTag(imageUrl);
        Picasso.get()
                .load(imageUrl)
                .into(avatar);

        // Render spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Constant.GENDER);
        gender.setAdapter(adapter);

        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ViewAdsActivity.this, EditAdsActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra("imageUrl", (String) avatar.getTag());
                intent.putExtra("genderPosition", gender.getSelectedItemPosition());
                intent.putExtra("name", name.getText().toString());

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**EditAdsActivity.java**

```
public class EditAdsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_ads);

        CircleImageView avatar = findViewById(R.id.avatar);
        EditText nameEditText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_name);
        Spinner gender = findViewById(R.id.spinner_gender);

        String imageUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("imageUrl");
        int genderPosition = getIntent().getIntExtra("genderPosition", 0);
        String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");

        // Render image view
        Picasso.get()
                .load(imageUrl)
                .into(avatar);

        // Render spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Constant.GENDER);
        gender.setAdapter(adapter);
        gender.setSelection(genderPosition);

        // Render edit text
        nameEditText.setText(name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the spinner you can use

```
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.your_spinner);
String text = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

And then place the text in the intent like the other objects.

An image is trickier because you don't want to serialize the bitmap for the intent since serialization is on the main thread and the app would probably stutter or hang a bit.  Instead you could store the bitmap in a class that is accessible from both activities, or if the image is already stored on the device you can pass the URI and just reopen it in the next activity.

Comment: This coding should put in which coding sir? As you can see, I'm using an intent to pass the data :)

Comment: You should not use an intent to pass a large image like a bitmap though because the serialization could be slow.  You could pass the URI of the image Or you can keep the image in a class that is retained between activities, this is where something like dependency injection would come in handy or a hacky way is to store it on the application object (but I don't recommend that